# How can i add css to a dynamically created div in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

i am using css to configure this div's properties using it's id, but it aint working, maybe because i created it in c# in the code behind, how can i fix that?
c#

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(@"<div id=""img1"" runat=""server"">Vidal</div>");
Label1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Css

```
#img1{
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
left: 20px;
width: 253px;height: 190px;
```

}

Comment: check the source of page if the div has same id..if you have masterpage the id will be changed..

Comment: Use css class instead of id

Comment: First, get rid of 'runas' - it won't add anything. 2nd, what does the source to the page look like when the browser renders it?

Comment: Also, remove the runat=server, as this isn't a server control.

Comment: Won't a label Html encode the value you try to store into it?

Answer (score 3):

I would use a class instead of an ID.  Also, you don't need to make it a div, as your Label will render as a span.  You simply need to set the `CssClass` and `Text` properties.

---

### C#

```cs
Label1.CssClass = "someClass";
Label1.Text = "Vidal";
```

---

### CSS

```css
.someClass
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;  
    left: 20px;
    width: 253px;
    height: 190px;
}
```

Comment: label will render as a span. adding a div inside span is not semantic. instead of label, use literal control.

Comment: @Ravimallya - That's true. I'll just have him use the CssClass and remove the div markup to the label itself.

Answer (score 1):

you can't use label control to display html content , use literal control or panel like below

```
Panel div = new Panel();
div.ID = "img1";   
div.Controls.Add(new Literal{Text = "Vidal"});    
this.Controls.Add(div);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think for your purposes, you might be better with asp:literal control:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<div class=\"image-css-selector">Vidal</div>");
Literal1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

A label control will have it's own markup and that might affect your html code

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a single webform, then please make sure that you do not have multiple ids. If you are using a master page, and you really need a `runat="server` attribute to the div then you need to change the css like this:

```
#ContentPlaceHolder_img1{
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
left: 20px;
width: 253px;height: 190px;
```

Where `ContentPlaceHolder` is the name of the  ID that you have gave for your content placeholder. for ex:

```
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
     </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

In your master page.